# Mongo Schema Design time series data

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a web application using MongoDB,and I have some questions about the schema design.

What I want to do is to use Mongo store energy consumption data for each user. For each user, we will have the data for electricity consumption, which is a time stamp and consumption.

So the questions is how to store them in Mongo, and I have two ways of doing it.

1. Put everything in one Collection. So it will have like this:

   `{"user_id": "e211a233-808f-fc43-0800-c05650001785","Value": 274,"Time": 1314691200}`

   So, each user may have thousands of data, and we have thousands of users. So there would be tens of millions documents in one collection.
2. Put the data of one user in one Collection. So we will have thousands of collections and thousands of document in each collection.

Can anyone help me which approach is better considering performance?

Comment: Arranging a benchmark test doesn't seem a big deal. And it would be your test, in your environment. By the way, why not 3. Put one user's data in a single document?

Comment: I haven't thought about one single document yet. I don't have all the data now, so I cannot test.

Comment: Having (embedding) all of one user's data in one document would make fetching details for a particular user very efficient. But if the number of consumption records per user is going to be huge, option-1 will make it easier if you plan on sharding that collection when needed.

Comment: What queries do you need to perform on the data? Is it just fetching the historical data for a particular user?

Comment: Sorry to reply so late. Yes, I want to fetch the data for one particular user

Answer (score 2):

For any new refers for this question:

mongoDB has some very useful video tutorials regarding this specific problem. see the following links and it will help you for sure:

[part 1](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/webinar-mongodb-time-series-data-setting-stage-sensor-management)

[part 2](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mongodb-time-series-data-part-2-analyzing-time-series-data-using-aggregation-framework)

[part 3](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mongodb-time-series-data-part-3-sharding)

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 will leverage your indexes and scale out well. It'll be much easier to query and update effieciently than massive documents that are always changing. It will also make your queries much easier if you plan on aggregating that data in the future. Specifically, using the Aggregation Framework over documents is much more efficient than arrays within documents which have to be unwound first.

Also, if you planned on having in the region of 150K entries like that, it would exceed the 16MB single document limit, so I think you're almost always better off with single documents in a big collection as per option 1.

**[Update]**

Looking again, I see that you you haven't mentioned what queries you would make over the data. That's the key to this. But given that it looks as if your results are historical It looks more and more towards putting the data into millions of documents. Map-Reduce would be your friend here for analysis.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The query I want is to fetch the data for one particular user

Answer (score 1):

You can do with option 1 and also shard your data across multiple nodes for performance.

Alternatively if it's an option, I would personally keep a daily entry for each user and then use

```
db.coll.update( 
  { _id : userId, date: '12/11/2012' }, 
  { $inc : {  consumption : value } },
  true // insert the document if it does not exist and init consumption with 0
)
```

If you will not be querying the data too often, you can also add the entries in a single daily document in a day collection like so:

```
db.days.update( { day: '12/11/2012' } , 
  { $addToSet : 
    { todaysConsumptions : { userId : id, consumption: value, time: timestamp } 
  } 
}
```

The way to query data from this last method would be to use the aggregation framework with the $unwind operation on the todaysConsumptions field. $unwind essentially converts an embedded array field into column like data which can then be grouped, summed, counted etc.

Comment: I don't think there's any benefit to a single document in this instance. The $unwind for the AF in this case would be really expensive. I'd steer clear of option 2 here.

Comment: It is more expensive so it is ideal if you do weekly or monthly queries to generate the bill etc. However it may potentially yield better performance if you could $limit to specific dates, so the amount of documents that you would $unwind would be very small, in contrast to $summing millions of smaller documents. Either way, testing for performance is king. I would generate 10 million random sample data and try both approaches to see what works best.

Comment: $summing is slow, but with $unwind it's a lot slower. Given the numbers he's talking about, my money's on millions of smaller documents versus less docs with an array of entries, *even if* it doesn't blow the 16MB limit trying to do the array and $unwind. I think this problem is ideally suited to Map Reduce.

Comment: Having said that - he hasn't actually specified what queries he wants to perform. We're guessing. So if all he needs to do is fetch all the data, you might be on the right lines with storing it as a single document, but I suspect that the inserts will be a lot slower (if the data fits within 16MB).